# How to arrange these bootstrap elements in an html page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a web page with html and bootstrap 4 and I'm having trouble arranging my page following this template.

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Hepatrote with Bootstrap v4</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <p class="h5 my-0 me-md-auto fw-normal">Hepatrote</p>
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Accueil</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Blog</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Symptoms</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Contacts</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="container">
    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">

      <!-- How to arrange these elements: left side : Symptoms with text and button 'How to protect yourself ?'
; rgiht side : Image of disease -->

      <!-- How to arrange these elements: Symptoms with text and 4 bootstrap cards With this arrangement-->
      <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center">

      </div>
      <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
      </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

In my code, you can see the based structure : head,body and I also added bootstrap link. My problem is to arrange the elements as shown in the picture.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: as long as your using Bootstrap4 so you need to read more about bs grid basics, you can learn from this [Reference: bootstrap grid basic](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic stracture of your image using bootstrap 4, this is not responsive so you need to some work for responsive.

Code:

```
    <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Hepatrote with Bootstrap v4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
  <body>
    
<header class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <p class="h5 my-0 me-md-auto fw-normal">Hepatrote</p>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Accueil</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Symptoms</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Contacts</a>
  </nav>
</header>

<main class="container">
  <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <h1>Symptoms</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
      <h1>Image of dieses</h1>
      </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">Syptoms</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 ">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block" >
                  <h5>Image1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block">
                  <h5>Sympt1</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block" >
                  <h5>Image1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block">
                  <h5>Sympt1</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block" >
                  <h5>Image1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block">
                  <h5>Sympt1</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block" >
                  <h5>Image1</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="w-50 d-inline-block">
                  <h5>Sympt1</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
  </footer>
</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Hi @Patrik Patel, in bootstrap card i want to add image to the left side exactly with the image that i posted. How can i do this

Comment: I have changed in above code,  Pleade check

Answer (score 0):

```css
main {
width:90%;
}

#maincss {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
}

#maincol {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin:auto;
  
}
#mainimg {
  position:relative;
  max-width:100%;
  }

#3rdcss {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

img {
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

#3rdcol {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
#cardzcol {
position:relative;
margin:auto;
padding:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <title>Hepatrote with Bootstrap v4</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
</head>

<body>

<header class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
  <p class="h5 my-0 me-md-auto fw-normal">Hepatrote</p>
  <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 me-md-3">
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Accueil</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Blog</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Symptoms</a>
    <a class="p-2 text-dark" href="#">Contacts</a>
  </nav>
</header>

  <main class="container">
    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">

      <div id="maincss" class="row">
        <div id="maincol" class="col-6">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>text relative</p>
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="button" />
        </div>
        <div id="maincol" class="col-6 ">
        <div id="mainimg"><img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" /></div></div>
        <div id="maincol" class="col-12 ">
          <div id="3rdcss" class="row ">
            <div id="3rdttl" class="col-12 ">
            <h2>Title</h2>
              <p>some more text to be shown</p>
            </div>
            <div id="cardzcol" class="col-6 ">
              <div id="cardz" class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="cardrw" class="row">
                    <div id="crdimgcol" class="col-6"><img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" /></div>
                    <div id="crdtxtcol" class="col-6">
                      <h5 class="card-title">[card-1]</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">some text here</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cardzcol" class="col-6 ">
              <div id="cardz" class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="cardrw" class="row">
                    <div id="crdimgcol" class="col-6"><img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" /></div>
                    <div id="crdtxtcol" class="col-6">
                      <h5 class="card-title">[card-2]</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">some text here</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cardzcol" class="col-6 ">
              <div id="cardz" class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="cardrw" class="row">
                    <div id="crdimgcol" class="col-6"><img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" /></div>
                    <div id="crdtxtcol" class="col-6">
                      <h5 class="card-title">[card-3]</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">some text here</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cardzcol" class="col-6 ">
              <div id="cardz" class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div id="cardrw" class="row">
                    <div id="crdimgcol" class="col-6"><img src="https://tmladenov.tech/images/img-test.png" title="img" /></div>
                    <div id="crdtxtcol" class="col-6">
                      <h5 class="card-title">[card-4]</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">some text here</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <footer class="pt-4 my-md-5 pt-md-5 border-top">
        [footer]
      </footer>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```